# Lualatex + amsthm + polyglossia + CharisSIL = error

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, amsthm, debugging, bugs

The following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,polyglossia}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Harmless definition
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

when run through lualatex, produces this error:

```
warning  (node filter): error: ...es/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-ha
rf-plug.lua:408: bad argument #1 to 'char' (value out of range)

.
\par ...@m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par 
                                                  }\fi 
l.12 \end{defi}
             
?
```

No error occurs with xelatex, nor with lualatex if I either remove amsthm or replace CharisSIL with either Times New Roman or Sylfaen.

What could be the reason?

Here is the log:

```
Command Line:   lualatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "test.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\me\Desktop\vv

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.11)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2

 L3 programming layer <2020-12-03> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
```

...

```
(./test.aux) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd")
warning  (node filter): error: ...es/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-ha
rf-plug.lua:408: bad argument #1 to 'char' (value out of range)

.
\par ...@m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par 
                                                  }\fi 
l.12 \end{defi}
             
? 
[1{C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux))
 411 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 49 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:35,3:14,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:154,9:12,11:6
<C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/fonts/truetype/SIL/charissil/charissil-r.tt
f><C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/fonts/truetype/SIL/charissil/charissil-i.
ttf><C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/fonts/truetype/SIL/charissil/charissil-
b.ttf>
```

Comment: This is just a very wild guess.  If you load CharisSIL before the other packages, is the result the same?  (Don't have access to the font, so can't test.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Wow your very wild guess is a very wise one! If I load `amsthm` after CharisSIL the error disappears. I still don't understand what happens but I believe it will be useful if you will make an answer out of your comment - somebody with similar problem will know what to try.

Comment: I gues this is something that the `luaotfload` and `polyglossia` people should have a look at.

Comment: I've added an answer as requested, but it's not clear to me whether the loading of `polyglossia` would be better in a different order.  Please feel free to make any necessary adjustment.

Comment: What seems to work for me is loading `fontspec`, then `\setmainfont`, then `amsthm` and `polyglossia`.

Comment: It is a bug in the luaotfload code for the HarfBuzz renderer which has been resolved in the development code. Polyglossia forces the HarfBuzz renderer and so trigger the bug, but you in the meantime can use the node renderer instead with the methods of Barbara or Davislor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I believe your comment contains the ultimate answer for the time being. Could you please make it an answer? It could then be updated eventually to a better one, when the development version becomes released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in the `luaotfload` code for the HarfBuzz renderer which has been resolved in the development code. `polyglossia` forces the HarfBuzz renderer and so triggers the bug, but in the meantime you can use the node renderer instead with the methods described in the answers of Barbara or Davislor.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be related to the LuaLaTeX HarfBuzz renderer somehow.  When I turn that off, your MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[luatexrenderer=Node]{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Harmless definition
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

This appears to work regardless of the loading order.  You can also set this as a font option, if you need the HarfBuzz renderer for another font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[Renderer=Node]
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Harmless definition
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

Another workaround might be to use XCharter as a replacement, since Charis SIL is based on Charter.

As a slight addendum to Barbara Beeton’s excellent workaround, be sure to load `\usepackage{fontspec}` before `\setmainfont` if you are moving `\usepackage{polyglossia}` further down.

Comment: I had a similar error with the package selnolig and polyglossia and lualatex v1.13 (but not 1.12):
`warning  (ligkern): error: ...Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/lualatex/selnolig/selno
lig.lua:134: bad argument #1 to 'char' (invalid value)`. The first solution here (`\usepackage[luatexrenderer=Node]{polyglossia}`) solved it, thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on a successful guess, as I don't have access to the Charis SIL font, and can't test.

This requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as Charis SIL is an 8-bit (`utf8`) font.

The font must be loaded *before* `amsthm`:

```
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

Comment: You would need to load  `fontspec` before using `\setmainfont`, though.

Comment: [Charis SIL is on CTAN.](https://ctan.org/pkg/charissil)

Comment: @Davislor -- thanks.  I'm working as a guest on a system I don't feel comfortable disrupting, so trying to test isn't a viable option.  Your answer looks good though.  +1